# g++ Compilation in AIX server - Throwing core dump

Tags: c++, c, g++, aix

I have the below code.

**cat sample.c**

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include "hello.c" 
int main()
 { 
hello_world(); 
return 0; 
 }
```

**cat hello.c**

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void hello_world() 
{ 
printf("Hello World"); 
}
```

- Compliation command Used:

  g++ -gxcoff -maix64 -shared -fpic -fpermissive -w -Ihello.c -o sample sample.c -Xlinker -e.main
- Execution

$ ./sample

Segmentation fault(coredump)

- I tried to Debug the core. But could not find much

  $ dbx sample core

  ```
  Type 'help' for help. 
  [using memory image in core] 
  reading symbolic information ...internal error: 1283-232 index("16;0;", ':') failed 

  internal error: 1283-232 index("16;0;", ':') failed 

  internal error: 1283-232 index("8;0;", ':') failed 

  internal error: 1283-228 expected char ',', found ';-31,448,256;;' 

  internal error: 1283-228 expected char ';', found ',256;;' 

  internal error: 1283-232 index("256;;", ':') failed

  Segmentation fault in . at 0x7c0802a6f8010010
  0x7c0802a6f8010010 (???) warning: Unable to access address 0x7c0802a6f8010010 from core
  ```

  Please help me how to resolve this core dump issue

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but *don't* `#include` source files! Instead compile them separately to object files and then link them together to form the final executable. What you should `#include` is a *header* file containing only *declarations*.

Comment: Does "gcc -o sample sample.c" work?

Comment: Yes, this works. But I would like to know the reason behind the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `g++ -gxcoff -maix64 -shared -fpic ...`

Above command builds a *shared library*, not an executable that you can run. Remove `-shared` from it, as well as `-Xlinker -e.main`, and it should just work.